# Will boost::format.parse() reset its buffer, too?

Tags: c++, boost, format

boost/format/format_class.hpp doesn't mention that parse() would run clear() first. Every examples I can found calls clear() before parse(). Is it necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it shouldn't be.

boost/format/format_class.hpp does mention this in it's file

```
basic_format& parse(const string_type&); // resets buffers and parse a new format string
```